# For a family of projections how to prove $\vee(I-E_a) \ge I-\wedge E_a$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

In the book "Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras" by Richard V. Kadison and John R. Ringrose at page 111 (a screenshot is attached below) the authors claims:

> Since **the map $E \to I-E$ reverses the ordering** of the projections we have $$\vee(I-E_a)=I-\wedge E_a$$

I have managed to prove $\vee(I-E_a) \le I-\wedge E_a$:

> By definition, $\forall a, E_a \ge \wedge E_a \implies \forall a, I-E_a \le I - \wedge E_a$ (since $E \to I-E$ is reversing)$\implies \vee(I-E_a) \le I-\wedge E_a$

But I am not able to see how does the fact that **"the map $E \to I-E$ reverses the ordering"** implies the other inequality i.e. $\vee(I-E_a) \ge I-\wedge E_a$.

Any hint or suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

.

[image: Screenshot of that page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $I-E_b\leq \lor(I-E_a)$. Then

$$
I-\lor(I- E_a)\leq E_b.
$$
As this holds for all $b$,
$$
I-\lor(I- E_a)\leq \land E_a,
$$
which is
$$
I-\land E_a\leq\lor(I-E_a).
$$